# Local interpolation of surfaces using normal vectors

Tags: math, 3d

I need to interpolate a 3D surface given it's points and normal vectors.

Given a point on it's surface, I need to find where that point would be in space once the interpolation has been accounted for. I need to be able to do this for each triangle in isolation.

Here's what I'm trying to describe. I need the position of the point once the curve / surface has been interpolated.

If I was working in 2D:
[image: before / after interpolation in 2D]

3D:
[image]

I've come across this paper ["Simple local interpolation of surfaces using normal vectors - Takashi Nagata"](http://cs.engr.uky.edu/~cheng/PUBL/Paper_Nagata.pdf) which I think demonstrates exactly what I'm looking for (section 2.2. Interpolation of a patch using normals), but the math is just beyond me.

What I'm trying to extract from it is a set of equations where the position and normals of the points comprising the triangle go in, as well as the point on the triangle, and the adjusted point comes out (like magic).

Comment: Your 3D example seems under-constrained. At the very least, you are looking at 3 cubic (or possible rational cubic) interpolations for each edge. This would suggest a (rational) cubic Bezier triangle, in which case you're looking at 10 control points. Mathematically elegant surfaces, but somewhat more involved than Bezier curves or tensor product surfaces. That said, they maintain many analogous properties since they are essentially a de'Casteljau construction.

Comment: I'm interested in a 2d version, would you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper looks like its trying to fit a quadratic surface so that it matches the points and normals you have. The resulting surface is given by

```
p(s,t) = c00 + c10 s + c01 t + c11 s t + c20 s^2 + c02 t^2
```

where s,t are the two variables, c00 etc are all vectors with three coordinates. s,t are chosen so at s=0,t=0 its your first point, s=1, t=0 is your second point and s=1,t=1 is your third point. Assuming we can find the various c00's you can pick some values of s,t in the triangle to give a middle point, s=2/3, t=1/3 might be a find candidate.

Find c00 etc will take some work. You probably need to implement eqn 15, which gives a curvature, as a function

```
vec3 c(vec3 D,vec3 n0,vec3 n1) {
    vec3 v = (n0 + n1)/2;         // 12a
    vec3 dv = (n0 - n1)/2;        // 12b
    double d = D.dot(v);          // 13a 
    double dd = D.dot(dv);        // 13b
    double c = n0.dot(n0 - 2*dv); // 14a
    double dc = n0.dot(dv);       // 14b
    vec3 res;
    if( c == -1 || c==1 )
        res = vec3.zeroVector;
    else
        res = dd / (1-dc) * v + d / dc * dv;
    return res;
}
```

assuming you have a vec3 class which can do basic vector operators.

With that defined, use 35, 36 to define the starting vectors and normals. Use 39 to define differences between pairs of points d1, d2, d3 and curvatures c1, c2, c3. The use eq 44

```
x(η, ζ ) = x00(1 − η) + x10(η − ζ ) + x11ζ
     − c1(1 − η)(η − ζ ) − c2(η − ζ )ζ − c3(1 − η)ζ
```

and your done.

Comment: Hey, so I've got it working (writing this in c# for unity, so have vector classes etc), but am trying to pick a sensible strategy for finding s and t. I've got a vector describing a position on the surface of the triangle to work with, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: One thing you could do is pick the midpoint on each edge. You could then connect these together giving a central triangle with three triangles surrounding it. Other options include using a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system to find the center of mass. There is also plenty of other candidates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center

Comment: Came across Barycentric coordinate whilst having a look around, did the job, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the records, and because I wanted to have this information somewhere on the web.

This is the 2d interpolation using the paper posted by the OP.

[image]

[image]

Where **1a** and **1b** are the boundary conditions, and the equations **4a** and **4b** are the x and y components of the vector **c** needed for the interpolation.